# Does an object move because it has Kinetic Energy or does it have Kinetic Energy because it is moving?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy, kinematics, reference-frames

Maybe to explain I'm wondering if an object gains $\rm K.E.$ which causes it to have a velocity or does an object have a velocity which cause it to get $\rm K.E.$?

Comment: Whether an object is moving or not and at what velocity it is moving is coordinate system dependent. There is one inertial observer who will say that the object is at rest and every other observer will say that it moves at some velocity. All inertial observers in physics are equivalent, so the kinetic energy doesn't matter that much... unless the object happens to collide with you.

Comment: Hi. I'd say that the problem here is more linguistic than physical. A moving object (in a certain reference frame) has kinetic energy. An object with kinetic energy is moving.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula for [kinetic energy](http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/energy/Lesson-1/Kinetic-Energy) tells you that movement is a necessary ingredient:

$$KE = \frac {1}{2} m v^2$$

where $m$ is mass
and $v$ is speed.

Without speed, there's no kinetic energy.  However, to an observer moving with the object, the object will **not** appear to have kinetic energy.  Other objects with different velocities, on the other hand, will appear to that observer to have kinetic energy.

If an object is at rest with respect to other objects, energy is necessary in order to overcome its inertia with respect to those objects.  Such energy can be a release of potential energy, or the transfer of kinetic energy from another object (a moving object).

Movement is relative to the observer.  Your question is sort of like asking whether the chicken or the egg comes first.  Actually, the observer comes first.

Answer (score 4):

In many cases, energy is best thought of as a relative quantity. It is changes in energy -- from kinetic to gravitational potential, etc -- that are physically meaningful. Absolute quantities have less meaning (though as some point out, rest mass, and its equivalent energy, are intrinsic, but if we're speaking only about non-relativistic mechanics then this is irrelevant).

Thus, kinetic energy can be thought of as the amount of work an object could perform on another object, by colliding with it. If the objects are moving at the same speed then no work can be performed, they can't collide.

Having a relative velocity and having kinetic energy are the same thing, one doesn't cause the other.

Answer (score 2):

The object is compelled to have the same velocity unless something is willing exchange both energy *and* momentum with it in a way that allows it to balance energy and momentum in the particular way that its mass requires:

$$E^2=\vec p^2c^2+(mc^2)^2.$$

Or, for slow speeds:

$$E\approx mc^2+\frac{\vec p^2}{2m}.$$

Otherwise it has to keep having that kinetic energy forever because it can't change its momentum.

So the real question is about changing the kinetic energy. And it has to get energy **and** momentum from something else or be stuck with **both** the energy and momentum it already has.

Answer (score 1):

Kinetic energy depends upon relative velocity. If the relative velocity vanishes, so does the kinetic energy.

Answer (score 0):

When a Force is applied, the object comes into motion. If force is applied over a displacement the velocity of the object increases significantly,. This velocity allows the object to do work on other objects. So we can say that an object possesses kinetic energy because of its motion. At the end of the day energy is the ability to do work and a moving object has the ability to bring other objects in motion so the first object has energy due to its motion. To sum up, when force is applied the object comes into motion and due to that motion the object gains some kinetic energy.

Answer (score -3):

Laymen's language -

It is the kinetic energy that moves the mass.

Energy is restlessness of the universe. It only rests in mass. That is why we say "rest mass". In that sense, it can also be called "rest energy"

When energy moves alone (in space), it moves at c.

When it moves a mass, it moves per KE = 1/2 * m * v * v.

KE can be movement of whole mass, or it can be random movements of its particles (heat energy).

When it rests in mass, it likes to rest together - gravity.

When it moves alone, it likes to spread - radiation/waves.

I am not sure about how electric/magnetic energy rests/moves (if we call them energy instead of fields/charges), may be someone can comment.

Comment: Kinetic energy is a scalar quantity. If it causes motion, how can it be that some objects with kinetic energy $e$ are caused to move in one direction, but other objects with the same amount of kinetic energy are caused to move in another direction?

Comment: Did I say anything about vector/scalar!

Comment: No, you didn't. That's why I raised the issue.

Comment: Direction is not an issue here. Obviously, a movement has to have a direction. Kinetic energy moves the body in that direction of movement. It can be a circular motion where direction keeps changing.

Comment: And how does it do that? The kinetic energy doesn't care about direction but the movement does.

Comment: Because KE is defined as scalar, we do not count the direction with it, but it is KE that moves the mass.

Comment: You're claiming that kinetic energy causes motion. How does a *directionless* quantity cause motion *in a particular direction*? Where does the direction come from?

Comment: OK that way distance is also a scalar quantity. But to measure a distance, you have to measure it in some direction. Direction is not an issue in the question. If the direction was an issue, then the question itself is not necessary, because we all know KE is scalar. Question does not even mention momentum or direction. It is talking about cause, not direction. The question has the word "cause" in it twice, "direction" - not even once. Please read it again. The question says velocity, but it really means motion in this context, not a directional speed.